# Having a Animated ScollView in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-animated

I was wondering if somebody is able to help me. I am building a login screen with a scrollview in React Native. However, the dreaded keyboard popping up over the inputs. I don't want to use KeyboardAvoidingView as I can't vertically centre the items the way that I want to.

I have got it sorted to the point that I can use contentOffset to move the scrollview, however not very nice to look at.

I want to use Animated.ScrollView to move it but it won't work. My Code below,

```
const scroll = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

function handleMoveScroll() {
    Animated.timing(scroll, {
        toValue: 50,
        duration: 3000,
        useNativeDriver: true
    }).start();
}

 <Animated.ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.screen} contentOffset={{ transform: [{ translateY: scroll }] }}>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!